# PHP var_dump is displaying NULL when using explode function

Tags: php, arrays, string, var-dump

My `var_dump` displays `NULL`

Below is my code:

```
$dareas = rtrim($areas,",");
$areasinarray = explode($dareas);

var_dump($areasinarray);
```

As far as the `$dareas` is concerned, it is a string which values are `15,12,14,19`

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: explode requires atleast 2 params.. syntactically wrong code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only supply the delimiter, not the string itself.

It should be

```
explode(",", $dareas);
```

Check out the [documentation](https://www.php.net/explode).

Comment: Oh yes! I keep missing the other delimeter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. you were trying to explode without any delimiter

```
<?php
$areas = "15,12,14,19";
$dareas = rtrim($areas,",");
$areasinarray = explode(',', $dareas);

var_dump($areasinarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

`explode();` requires another parameter - the delimiter. [See the manual.](https://www.php.net/explode) In your case that'd be a comma.

`explode(',', $dareas);`

Also, when developing, set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`. That'll catch mistakes like this.

Comment: where can I set that?

Comment: Put it at the very top of your PHP file. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$areasinarray = explode(',' ,$dareas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode needs 2 parameters. The first is the delimiter("," in your case) and the second parameter has to be your string($dareas). Check http://be1.php.net/explode for more info.